# Найдите ошибку

Tags: html, css, php

Помогите найти ошибку, я сидел делал и вдруг обновил сайт, смотрю , а там всё как по стандарту вот мои коды:

*header.php*

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/widget_logo.gif">
<table align='center' width='26%'>
<tr>
<td colspan='0'><img src="/images/В online.png" type="images" class="SuperImages" />

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tb>

</td>
</tr>
<table>

<body>
<td><span style='position: relative;bottom: 3px;margin-left:2200px'>
<div id="container">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li id="selected"><a href="/">Главная</a></li>
        <li><a href="/feed.php">Новости</a></li>
        <li><a href="../bkock/офф сайт">Офф. сайт О.А.Андреевича</a></li>
        <li><a href="o_site.php">О сайте</a></li>
        <li><a href="login.php">Выход</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</span></td>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.spasticNav.js"></script>

</body>
```

*index.php*

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/widget_logo.gif">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<title>online</title>
</head>

<body>
<tr>
<?php include("/style.css"); ?>
<tr>
<?php include ("blocks/header.php"); ?>
<tr>
</tr>

</body>
</html>
<body>  
</body>
```

*style.css*
    <style>
    * {
      font-family: verdana;
      font-size: 12px
    }

```
a {
  text-decoration: none; /* убираем у ссылок подчеркнутость, заданную по-умолчанию */
  color:#4169e1;

ul{border-radius:20px;}

    background-image: url(images/fon.png);

#container {
    width: 1200px;
    margin: -4px auto;
}
ul, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#blob {
    background: #0b2b61;
    border-right: 1px solid #0059ec;
    border-left: 1px solid #0059ec;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0b2b61, #1153c0);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0b2b61), to(#1153c0));
     border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 2px 3px 10px #011331;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 3px 10px #011331;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 3px 10px #011331;
}
#nav {
    position: relative;
    background: #292929;
    float: left;
}
#nav li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #4a4a4a;
    border-left: px solid black;
}
#nav li a {
    color: #e3e3e3;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 49px;
    width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Извините, ответа не жду, потому что уже сам нашел,это не нужное
a {
  text-decoration: none; /* убираем у ссылок подчеркнутость, заданную по-умолчанию */
  color:#4169e1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<body>
<tr>
<?php include("/style.css"); ?>
<tr>
<?php include ("blocks/header.php"); ?>
```

Может, конечно, я что-то путаю, но разве стили не надо подключать в хеде?

Comment: ой щяс обязательно подключю в хеде

Answer (score 0):

1.Верстайте через div.Таблици нужны для отображения табличных данных.

2.Подключение jquery должно идти в секции head

3.Используйте Firebug

4.ul{border-radius:20px;}

```
background-image: url(images/fon.png);
```

Answer (score 0):

Тут весь подход одна сплошная ошибка.

<body>  - может быть только одно в документе. Верстка таблицами умерла лет 10 назад. Даже если таблицами верстать, то надо хотя бы соблюдать правила написания.

Пример:

```
<tr>
<tb>

</td>
</tr>
<table>

<body>
```

Вам надо переделать чуть более чем полностью. Потратьте 5-6 часов вашего драгоценного времени на изучение тэгов и "новых" веяний и у вас получится замечательный сайт :)

Comment: да  я знаю теги не в правильном порядке поставил